# Rotation on a newer version of OpenGL (How to rotate while not using glRotatef)

Tags: java, opengl, rotation, 2d, shader

So I started working on a game with the new OpenGL versions in specific **(3.2)**.
I am using shaders and VBOs.

**How can I implement rotation?** (I used to just use glRotatef) I would rather do it through the program and not the shaders because I dont understand shader coding at all.. I don't even know where to start with the rotation because I cant think of how it would work..

**NOTE:** I need a simple way for a **2D** game.. I want to rotate triangles (that make up a quad) around themselves..

*Go into detail with examples..*

EDIT: My vertex shader

```
#version 150 core

in vec4 in_Position;
in vec4 in_Color;
in vec2 in_TextureCoord;
in float in_angle;

out vec4 pass_Color;
out vec2 pass_TextureCoord;

void main(void) {
    mat4x4 roll=mat4x4(1.0);
    roll[0][0]=cos(in_angle);
    roll[0][1]=sin(in_angle);
    roll[1][0]=-(sin(in_angle));
    roll[1][1]=cos(in_angle);


    gl_Position = in_Position*roll;

    pass_Color = in_Color;
    pass_TextureCoord = in_TextureCoord;
}
```

Comment: Whilst you can do rotation via the CPU, you REALLY should learn to use shaders to do this. Shader code is not that hard at all, the biggest thing to know is probably just that you use a 'uniform' to set a value (such as rotation) that will be used within the shader that can change frame by frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to implement a 2d scene I personally would recomand libgdx. But back to topic: Rotation can only be done in shaders. You have to transform the vertices according to the linear algebra http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix. What you do is implement a matrix class and all the operations like translations, rotations and scaling and feed this matrix to the shader. The most important part for this matrix is the projection but I gues you only need parallel projection which is easy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_projection

This is a example vertex shader:

```
  uniform mat4 matrix;
  void main(void) 
      {
          gl_Position = matrix * gl_Vertex;
      }
```

This shader transforms all your vertices by multiplying it by the matrix. Next you need a fragment shader:

```
void main(void)
    {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
```

You have to compile this by the opengl API and run it.

Comment: Wikipedia is such a bad source I hate it so much.. This is what I want you to add: Taking an angle, turning it into a rotation matrix, and then feeding it to the shaders you gave me. Example: I have 86 degrees i turn it to a mat4 object and pass it to the shader. Btw I am getting my degrees from JBox2D so it is for sure going to be valid degrees.

Comment: (I want you to add examples for what I said above..) Thank you!

Comment: What opengl bindding do you use?

Comment: Light Weight Java Game Library - (LWJGL)

Comment: Here is a complete example of a shader in lwjgl: http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=GLSL_Shaders_with_LWJGL And this is absolut great: https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/ShaderLesson1 I don't see the reason why I should repeat the basics if there are very good tutorials.

Comment: There is a few problems, first off the first tutorial is using deprecated methods, which I am avoiding and also the reason I am asking this. Also I have shaders set-up but I just dont understand how to setup rotation. I am successfully rendering a scene with 4 objects using shaders, passing to them 3 floats for XYZ another 3 floats for RGB and another 2 floats for ST coords. I don't understand how I pass in an angle that will somehow tell the shaders to rotate the element.

Comment: Ok, so the simplest way would be: Pass the angle to the shader and transform the (x,y) vector with this rotation matrix: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix you just have to look at the first formula in the first line in the article. You can wrap this formula in a function in the shader and call this when you transform the vertices.

Comment: EDIT: *** After experimenting I managed to pass an angle for each object but the results are weird.. I think the problem is how I calculate it in my vertex shader.. I added my vertex shader to the question, tell me if its correct..